# Excel - Function to use in CHOOSE - Return list of values from range

Tags: excel

Which excel function can I use in this CHOOSE formula to convert the range to a list and allow the return of the below CHOOSE function to be **b**

Example this problem to get value 'b'. Where range B2:F2 is equal to a,b,c,d,e.

```
CHOOSE(2, B2:F2)
```

This will fail as we have supplied a range to choose not a list.

Comment: why not ***INDEX()*** ???

Comment: I can use index and am exploring choose. Cannot see many times with CHOOSE where I would sit and enter all its choices. Mostly they would be ranges, there should be a logical way to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

To do this with `CHOOSE` you have to split the range in to individual cells, i.e.

`=CHOOSE(2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2)`

Answer (score 0):

You should "choose" a more appropriate function:

```
=INDEX(B2:F2,2)
```

[image]

Comment: all progress depends on the unreasonable man - George Bernard Shaw